# Parse a formatted string into a map which has same key many times?

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, splitter

I have a String which is coming in particular format so I want to parse that string into map. I have a below method which parses String to a Map and it works fine.

```
  public static Map<String, String> parseStringToMap(String payload) {
    try {
      return Maps.newHashMap(Splitter.on("|").withKeyValueSeparator("=").split(payload));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      return ImmutableMap.of();
    }
  }
```

Sample example of a string:

```
"type=3|Id=23456|user=13456"
```

Now sometimes when I have same key twice with same value in the same String `payload`, then my above method fails and it throws exception. For example for below string, it doesn't work and it fails and then it returns empty map because it has `type` key twice.

```
"type=3|Id=23456|user=13456|type=3"
```

What can I do to fix this instead of fixing the string payload? So let's say if same key comes many times, then overwrite that key value in the map instead of failing. And I want to return a Mutable map back.

I am still working with Java 7. What is the best and efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are you able to use Java 8? If so, you can use a grouping collector, to build a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, or similar.

Comment: @AndyTurner Unfortunately I am still on Java 7 and cannot use Java 8 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it in Guava, but it's not too hard to do with plain old Java:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String part : payload.split("\\|")) {
  String[] subparts = part.split("=", 2);
  map.put(subparts[0], subparts[1]);
}
return map;
```

If you want to check just that the string is in the right format (i.e. there are pipe-separated elements, each containing an `=` sign), then you can just use `indexOf` to find these:

```
int start = 0;
while (start < payload.length()) {
  int end = payload.indexOf('|', start);
  if (end == -1) {
    end = payload.length();
  }

  int equalsPos = payload.indexOf('=', start);
  if (equalsPos > end || equalsPos < 0) {
    // No = found between adjacent |s. Not valid format.
    return Collections.emptyMap();
  }

  // Extract the substrings between | and =, and = and the next |.
  map.put(payload.substring(start, equalsPos), payload.substring(equalsPos + 1, end));

  start = end + 1;
}
```

Comment: With this way how can I check if they are in that format only? If they are not in that format, then return back empty map? Or should I just wrap this up in try catch and it will throw exception on its own if they are not in that format and basis on that return empty map?

Comment: What do you mean by "not in that format"? That there is an `=`, then a `|`, then an `=` etc, with characters in between? Sure: just search for those in the string using indexof.

Comment: Yes it has to be in this format only and if it is not then return empty map.

Comment: I tried your edited suggestion on this payload which is not in the valid format `type=3:Id=23456|user=13456|type=3` and it doesn't return empty map as it thinks this is a valid string.

Comment: In what way isn't that valid? It's got an equals sign between all of the pipes (/start and end of the string). That there is more than one equals in the first value doesn't automatically make it invalid; that's just your (unstated) requirement. If that's what you want, though, why not have a go at adapting this code? It's not a very hard change.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation says that split will throw an exception if there are duplicate keys:

> @CheckReturnValue public Map split(CharSequence
>   sequence)
>
> Splits sequence into substrings, splits each substring into an entry,
>   and returns an unmodifiable map with each of the entries. For example,
>   Splitter.on(';').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=>")
>   .split("a=>b ; c=>b") will return a mapping from "a" to "b" and "c" to
>   b.
>
> The returned map preserves the order of the entries from sequence.
>
> Throws:
>       IllegalArgumentException - if the specified sequence does not split into valid map entries, or if there are duplicate keys

So, you can't use the split from MapSplitter, sorry!

With Java 8:

```
    return Splitter
        .on("|")
        .splitToList(payload)
        .stream()
        .map(kv -> kv.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(kv -> kv[0], kv -> kv[1], (d1, d2) -> d1));
```

Comment: Yeah so is there any better way to do this then apart from Splitter?

Comment: @user1950349 Maybe you could fix your input using a regex first?

Comment: I am still on Java 7 unfortunately.